# Mapping Date Strings to Dates including Time with Jackson in Spring

Tags: spring, date, spring-boot, jackson, jodatime

I'm using Spring Boot 1.4 and the following works. I have this `@Bean` defined:

```
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
    return new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(mapper);
}
```

And I have this DTO defined:

```
public class ReportRequest implements Serializable {
    private LocalDate startDate;
    private LocalDate endDate;
    // additional fields and getters/setters omitted
}
```

I'm submitting this data into a controller with `@RequestBody ReportRequest` with the following json in the body of the request:

```
{
    "startDate": "2016-09-01",
    "endDate": "2016-09-12"
}
```

Works great. However, I need to also include the time. So I changed everything to look like this:

```
mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));

private LocalDateTime startDate;
private LocalDateTime endDate;

{
    "startDate": "2016-09-01 02:00:00",
    "endDate": "2016-09-12 23:59:59"
}
```

This does not work. I'm getting:

```
Could not read document: Invalid format: \"2016-09-01 02:00:00\" is malformed at \" 02:00:00\" (through reference chain: com.hightouchinc.dto.ReportRequest[\"startDate\"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Invalid format: \"2016-09-01 02:00:00\" is malformed at \" 02:00:00\" (through reference chain: com.hightouchinc.dto.ReportRequest[\"startDate\"])
```

Update: I modified the following:

```
mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"));
```

And can send `"2016-09-01T02:00:00"` and it works. But removing the `T` from both continues to break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear that `LocalDateTimeDeserializer` respects the value passed to `setDateFormat()`, as can be seen in `JodaModule`:

```
addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeDeserializer());
```

What you can do is override the default deserializer in the module before registering it:

```
JodaModule jodaModule = new JodaModule();
JacksonJodaDateFormat format = new JacksonJodaDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
jodaModule.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeDeserializer(format)));
mapper.registerModule(jodaModule);
```

and that should use the correct pattern to deserialize your `LocalDateTime` instances.

Comment: That's a good idea, but `JacksonJodaDateFormat` doesn't accept a String. It needs a DateTimeFormatter so I'm trying to determine how to wrap it correctly.

Comment: So it does.  You can create it from the string with `DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");`

Comment: You can't, because that `DateTimeFormat` is from java.text and `JacksonJodaDateFormat` wants a joda time `DateTimeFormatter` which doesn't work the same way.

Comment: I also had to add `mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);` otherwise I got the date sectioned out as a list. But everything else works great. Thanks.